# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"h2"}

Tags: python, selenium

In the below code I am unable to move to the next page. If somebody could help me would be of great help. I am writing this script in Python and using selenium chrome webdriver.

I'm getting error at the end of the page.
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"h2"}
(Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.63)

```
import xlwt
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import time
from datetime import date
class kotsovolosmobiles:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url='https://www.kotsovolos.gr/mobile-phones-gps/mobile-phones/smartphones'
        self.country='GR'
        self.currency='euro'
        self.VAT= 'Included'
        self.shipping = 'Available for shipment'
        self.Pre_PromotionPrice ='N/A'
    def kotsovolos(self):        
        wb = xlwt.Workbook()
        ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
        ws.write(0,0,"Product_Url")
        ws.write(0,0,"Product_Manufacturer")
        ws.write(0,1,"Product_Url")
        ws.write(0,2,"Product_Price")
        ws.write(0,3,"Product_Model")
        ws.write(0,4,"Memory")
        ws.write(0,5,"Currency")
        ws.write(0,6,"Color")
        ws.write(0,7,"VAT")
        ws.write(0,8,"Shipping Cost")
        ws.write(0,9,"Pre-PromotionPrice")
        ws.write(0,10,"Country")
        ws.write(0,11,"Date")
        ws.write(0,12,"Raw_Model")
        wb.save(r"C:\Users\Karthick R\Desktop\VS code\kotsovolos.xls")
        driver=webdriver.Chrome()            
        driver.get(self.url)
        today = date.today()
        time.sleep(5)
        cookies = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[id="CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"]')
        cookies.click()
        print("cookies accepted")
        driver.maximize_window() 
        time.sleep(5)
        titles = []
        models = []
        memorys = []
        prod_prices = []
        p_links =[]
        p_colors = []  
        x = 15 
        while True: 
            storage_box = []          
            storage_box = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="product"]')
            for storage_boxes in storage_box:
                product_url = storage_boxes.find_element_by_tag_name('h2')
                product_urls = product_url.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
                print(product_urls)
                p_links.append(product_urls)

                p_model = storage_boxes.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="title"] a').text
                print(p_model)
                models.append(p_model)

                manufacturer1 = p_model.split(" ")
                print(manufacturer1[0])
                titles.append(manufacturer1[0])

                memory = []
                memory = re.findall('\d+ ?[gG][bB]',p_model)
                print(memory)
                memory1 = str(memory).replace("['",'').replace("']",'').replace("[]",'').strip()
                if "," in memory1:
                    arr=memory1.split(",")
                    for str1 in arr:
                        str2=str1.replace("GB", "").replace("gb", "").replace("'", "").strip() 
                        if len(str2)!=1: 
                            memory_str=str1
                            break 
                elif (memory1 == ""):
                    memory_str ='N/A'
                else:
                    memory_str=memory1 
                memory_str = memory_str.replace("'", "").strip() 
                print(memory_str)
                memorys.append(memory_str)

                colors= []
                prod_color = p_model.split(" ")
                length = len(prod_color)
                indexcolor = length-3 
                colors.append(prod_color[indexcolor])
                color1 = str(colors).replace("['",'').replace("']",'').strip()
                print(color1)
                p_colors.append(color1)

                p_price = storage_boxes.find_element_by_css_selector('.priceWithVat > .price').text
                print(p_price)
                prod_prices.append(p_price)
            next = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pagination_next a')
            url = next.get_attribute('href')
            driver.get(url)

kotsovolos_gr = kotsovolosmobiles()
kotsovolos_gr.kotsovolos()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite self explanatory that there's no tag with `h2` under this `css_selector`

```
div[class="product"]
```

I would advise to replace that with `a` tag.

Since I see this in `HTML DOM`

```
<a href="https://www.kotsovolos.gr/mobile-phones-gps/mobile-phones/smartphones/221351-apple-iphone-12-64gb-black" title="https://www.kotsovolos.gr/mobile-phones-gps/mobile-phones/smartphones/221351-apple-iphone-12-64gb-black" data-uw-rm-brl="false"><img src="https://assets.kotsovolos.gr/product/221351-m.jpg" alt="Apple iPhone 12 64GB Black" data-uw-rm-ima-original="apple iphone 12 64gb black"></a>
```

which is inside of a this `css_selector`

```
div[class="product"]
```

also, technically you do not need `h2` at all. The below code should do the magic for you.

```
storage_box = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class="product"]')
    for storage_boxes in storage_box:
                product_urls = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
                print(product_urls)
                p_links.append(product_urls)
```

Also, I am not sure if you are looking for heading of each product, in case you are

```
time.sleep(2)
storage_box = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product']")
for storage_boxes in storage_box:
    time.sleep(1)
    product_url = storage_boxes.find_element_by_xpath(".//h2")
    product_urls = product_url.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
    print(product_urls)
    p_links.append(product_urls)
```

Comment: no it is not working facing issue i was not able to move to next page.

Comment: using 1st coding i was not getting the website link and using 2nd coding i was unable to go to next page. my issue is i wanted to loop the pages till end and need to scrape the data